# Running all containers in detached mode

Tags: docker-compose

Iv'e recently started to work with `docker-compose` and I wondered how can I start all containers in my `docker-compose` file in detached mode.

After searching on the web for a bit I found a solution which was:
add the following properties to a container `tty: true` and `stdin_open: true` and then I attach to container and detach with `ctrl + p` and `ctrl + q` without killing the container.

The simple ang ugly solution it to add the properties to all containers, but I wonder if there is s nicer solution for this, maybe something with the `docker-compose up` that can somehow start **all** containers in detached mode

Comment: Did you mean `docker-compose up -d` ?

Comment: Not exactly, because when attaching to container after running it with `-d` and then trying to detach from it with `ctrl + c` the container gets killed

Answer (score 0):

To start containers in detached mode (as already mentioned above) you need to use the `docker-compose up -d`.

If you need to manually get in and out of the running container once it's started to perform some additional tasks, you can use [`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/).